# hide bootstrap modal from javascript without using jquery

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How to hide bootstrap modal from javascript without using jquery.
None of the following work :

```
document.getElementById('id_1').modal('toggle');
document.getElementById('#id_1').modal('toggle');
document.getElementById('id_1').modal('hide');
```

If I add a class `hide` it works. The modal hides, But the main screen stays grey. Focus never shifts to the main screen until I click on the screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-if` attribute on modal to toggle it. `<b-modal v-if="isVisible">`

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solution but the one I created and worked for me is:
add a close button (the default one given by Bootstrap modal template) and if you want you can add a `d-none` class to it if you want to hide it.

Then in your Javascript code :

```
var close = document.getElementById("closeButton");
close.click();
```